# ¿Por que la función lambda no me retorna nada y si hago una iteracion si?

Tags: reactjs, lambda

```
 render(){

 const elements = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

return(
    <div className="filterMenu">
        <div className="filterTag">
 <InputLabel id="label">Age</InputLabel>
 <Select labelId="label" id="select" value="10">
 {()=> <MenuItem value="10" >3</MenuItem>}
 </Select>
</div>
```

Si utilizo esta implementacion ()=> no me retorna el item, pero si en cambio hago este mapeo:

```
render(){
    const elements = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

   return(
    <div className="filterMenu">
        <div className="filterTag">
<InputLabel id="label">Age</InputLabel>
<Select labelId="label" id="select" value="10">
{elements.map((value, index) => {
       return <MenuItem key={index}>{value}</MenuItem>
      })}
</Select>
</div>
```

Los valores los devuelve perfectamente uno a uno, por que con la primera implementacion no retorna nada y en cambio con la segunda lo hace perfectamente

Answer (score 1):

No te retorna nada porque con `()=> <MenuItem value="10" >3</MenuItem>` estás declarando una referencia a una función (que no está siendo ejecutada). Es decir, estás creando una función pero no la estás llamando.

Sin embargo, con

```
elements.map((value, index) => {
 return <MenuItem key={index}>{value}</MenuItem>
})
```

estás devolviendo un `array` de elementos (`<MenuItem>`)

Answer (score 0):

No hay necesidad de hacer así

```
{()=> <MenuItem value="10" >3</MenuItem>}
```

Si sustituyes eso con esto, ya funcionaria

```
<MenuItem value="10" >3</MenuItem>
```